# Sequence, convergence determine a variable

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Determine X, soo the sequence below is convergent:

$$a_n = \frac{n+(2X-4)(-n)^3}{n+1}$$

I'm not sure how to solve this. Should I try to divide them all by $n^3$ to shorten the expression?

Comment: What means $x$ here?

Comment: It is a real number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Diving by $n^{3}$ leaves you with  $1+\lim \frac {4-2X} {(n+1)n^{-3}}$. so the limit exists only if $X=2$. The limit is $1$ in this case.

[ Separate $\frac n {n+1}$ before dividing by $n^{3}$].

Comment: i think you mean $n^3$ not $3^n$?

Comment: @GhostAmarth Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thank you, but how do you know that the limit is 1?

Comment: When $X=2$ we get $a_n=\frac n {n+1}$ so $lim_n a_n=1$.  @LionessQueen

Comment: Okay, thank you so much. And If I may ask another question: if we have another sequence, a_n = sin((Xn^2+1)/(Xn^2-1)), then how do I determine X so that a_n doesn't converge towards sin(1)? Cause in this case, I also divide by n^2, and I get sin((X+1/n^2)/(X-1/n^2)), but then from this I get sin(1), which it should not be?

Comment: @LionessQueen When $X=0$ the limit is $\sin (-1)$ For all other $X$ the limit is $\sin (1)$.

Comment: Alright, thank you so very much :)